# Query to Select Between Two Times of Day

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to build a query that will select based on a `DateTime` column `SyncDate`.

As some background, the table I query from gets imports daily in the thousands at the exact same time everyday. I want to find the entries that did not import at the "regular" time of day.

Therefore, I want to query where the time in the `DateTime` column is between two times: lets say 14:00-14:30 (2-230) on ANY day/month/year period.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE DatePart(SyncDate, ..?) BETWEEN (14:00..?) and (14:30..?)
```

The `DatePart` function seems to be what I need, but I don't understand how to apply it to this situation. Your help is much appreciated oh great queriers.

EDIT: I was mistaken, I am running SQL-Server-2005 as my backend.  Sorry!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since you're on SQL Server **2008**, you can use the new `TIME` datatype:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE CAST(SyncDate AS TIME) BETWEEN '14:00' and '14:30'
```

If your backend isn't 2008 yet :-) then you'd need something like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, SyncDate) = 14 AND DATEPART(MINUTE, SyncDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 30
```

to check for 14:00-14:30 hours.

Comment: Weird.  I'm running 2008, it recognizes 'time' as a keyword, but says it is not a 'defined system type'.

Comment: Is your server backend running 2008, or is it just your copy of SQL Server Mgmt Studio?? Checked it on 2008 R2 and it should work just fine....

Comment: You are correct, just the studio.  Is the backend the MDAC version or how do I check that?

Comment: `SELECT @@Version` should give you the database's version

Comment: Dang, my bad -- I am running 2005.

Comment: @ImGreg: my second query (updated my response) should work on 2005

Comment: That's the one.  Thanks @marc_s, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

How about this....

```
select * from MyTable where
cast(cast(datepart(HH,SyncDate) as char(2)) + cast(datepart(HH,SyncDate) as char(2)) as int) between 1400 and 1430
```

Comment: Kind of iffy method.  However, take out the cast as int and put apostrophes around the '1400' and it actually works.  +1 for an innovative approach.